# what does the "16be" mean in yuv420p16be

Tags: ffmpeg, format, yuv

I get some YUV pictures, their formats are yuv420p16le and yuv420p16be, I can convert them into jpg using ffmpeg, but I do not know what does the "16le" and the "16be" mean? Thanks a lot:-)

Comment: 16 = 16 bits, be = [big endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Big-endian), le = [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) ?

Comment: This is correct. Why did you post it as a comment, and not an answer?